# Why currency code is "000" from calling [Answers logAddToCartWithPrice]

Tags: google-fabric

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32REk.png)

I use [Answers logAddToCartWithPrice] to log purchase, but in log the currency code is 000, why?
may be I pass the nil to logAddToCartWithPrice's currency argument?

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. If a nil value is set for the currency code, then we switch to 000 so that the date can be processed correctly without affecting other currency's that have a valid code.